# having trouble in vs code for node js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I installed nodemon globally in my machine and then tried to run debug (I did this for the debugger to automatically restart), and then I got this error. What is the solution? 
[image: error message in terminal and in popup box]

Comment: Can you post your full code? Is the port you are using available to be used?

Comment: well @PedroSilva i managed it somehow the nodemon was giving errrors when i installed it globally but after i installed it locally in my machine everything works fine...dunno why